# Error de sintaxis con el siguiente script en batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Estoy haciendo un script que se encargará de hacer un usb bootable a partir de unos archivos y tiene diversas opciones, pero no me funciona, y al no conocer muy bien el lenguaje, pues creo que tengo más de uno y más de dos problemas de sintaxis, a ver si alguien puede echarme un cable a corregir esto, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

También necesito que el comando diskpart list disk muestre la lista de dispositivos conectados, pero no sé cómo hacer un echo sobre un comando.

Cualquier consejo / mejora es aceptada!

```
@echo off
set isNumber=false
set validEntry=false
set 1=false
set 2=false

mkdir so
echo Script para crear usb boot
echo ------------------------------------------------------
echo Debe descomprimir el contenido de la iso del sistema operativo
echo en la carpeta 'so' que viene con el script.
echo ------------------------------------------------------
echo Por el contrario, debe montar la iso 
echo virtualmente e introducir la ruta de los archivos.
echo ------------------------------------------------------

:validate
set /p "option=Va a montar la iso o a descomprimir los archivos en la carpeta 'so'? ('1' para descomprimir / '2' para montar): "

if %option% equ 1( 
    %validEntry%=true 
    %1%=true
)

if %option% equ 2 (
    %validEntry%=true
    %2%=true
)

if %validEntry% equ true(
    diskpart list disk

    :select_disk
    set /p "disk=Introduzca el número del disco correspondiente: "

    if %disk% EQU 0 %isNumber%=true
    if %disk% GRT 0 %isNumber%=true

    if %isNumber% equ true (
        diskpart select disk %disk%
        diskpart clean
        diskpart create partition primary
        diskpart active
        diskpart format fs=fat32
        diskpart assign
    )else(
        echo El valor introducido no es correcto, vuelva a intentarlo.
        goto select_disk
    )

    if %1% equ true(
        set /p path=Introduzca la ruta del disco que desea convertir en bootable (Por ejemplo E:\):
        xcopy /s/e/f so\*.* %path%
    )

    if %2% equ true(
        set /p path_iso=Introduzca la ruta del archivo iso montado (Por ejemplo E:\):
        set /p path_disk=Introduzca la ruta del disco que desea convertir en bootable (Por ejemplo F:\):
        xcopy /s/e/f %path_iso%\*.* %path_disk%
    )

)

if %validEntry% equ false(
    echo El valor introducido es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo.
    goto validate
)
```

Comment: Has probado a lanzarlo desde cmd ? Podrías hacerlo y comprobar si tienes errores de sintaxis , y en caso de no poder/saber resolverlos , los añades a la pregunta y podríamos serte de más ayuda que simplemente revisarte el trabajo línea por línea.

Comment: Si tienes errrores de sintaxis al ejecutarlo deberia marcarte linea y columna donde está el error. Tambien debe haber herramientas online que aseguren la correcta sintaxis de tu codigo. Para lo del `echo` sobre un comando, has probado algo? por que no te funciono? Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: lois6b disculpa, he probado redireccionando el comando algo así como echo >> diskpart list disk pero nada... y ejecutándose solo tampoco muestra ningún resultado.

Comment: referente a Marcos, desde el cmd me dice: La sintaxis del comando no es correcta

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes pero no he podido comprobar algún otro error ya que no dispongo de el ".iso" que requiere el código, espero ayudarte.

```
@echo off
set isNumber=false
set validEntry=false
set 1=false
set 2=false

mkdir "%~d0%~p0SO"
Echo.
echo Script para crear usb boot
echo ------------------------------------------------------
echo Debe descomprimir el contenido de la iso del sistema operativo
echo en la carpeta 'so' que viene con el script.
echo ------------------------------------------------------
echo Por el contrario, debe montar la iso 
echo virtualmente e introducir la ruta de los archivos.
echo ------------------------------------------------------

:validate
Echo.
Echo ¨Va a montar la iso o descompirimir los archivos en la carpeta "SO"?
Echo.
Echo [1] DESCOMPRIMIR.
Echo .
Echo [2] MONTAR.

choice /c 12 /n
if %errorlevel%==1 (
set "validentry=true"
set "1=true"
)

if %errorlevel%==2 (
set "validentry=true"
set "2=true"
)


if /i %validEntry% == true (
diskpart list disk
)

:select_disk
set /p "disk=Introduzca el número del disco correspondiente: "

if %disk% geq 0 set "isNumber=true"

if /i %isNumber% == true (
diskpart select disk %disk%
diskpart clean
diskpart create partition primary
diskpart active
diskpart format fs=fat32
diskpart assign
)else(
echo El valor introducido no es correcto, vuelva a intentarlo.
goto select_disk
)
:b_1
if /i %1% == true(
set /p path=Introduzca la ruta del disco que desea convertir en bootable (Por ejemplo E:\):
if not exist "%path%" (goto b_1)
xcopy /s/e/f so\*.* %path%
)

:b_2
if /i %2% == true(
set /p path_iso=Introduzca la ruta del archivo iso montado (Por ejemplo E:\):
if not exist "%path_iso%" (goto b_2)
set /p path_disk=Introduzca la ruta del disco que desea convertir en bootable (Por ejemplo F:\):
if not exist "%path_disk%" (goto b_2)
xcopy /s/e/f %path_iso%\*.* %path_disk%
)

)

if /i %validEntry% == false(
echo El valor introducido es incorrecto, vuelva a intentarlo.
goto validate
)
```